# QSqlTableModel dataChanged

Tags: qt

I'm using the following command to update a column on a particular table view:

```
connect(sale,SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex,QVector<int>)),this,SLOT(calculateSALE(QModelIndex)));
```

The function *calculateSALE(QModelIndex)*, calculates several things on the particular column pointed by QModelIndex. It works perfect, no problems here.

There are certain times where i want to call calculateSALE(QModelIndex) directly in a for() loop to recalculate all the columns in the table. I'm puzzled as how to create a dummy QModelIndex where i can loop the column number.

What i want to do is to call, this function:

```
void calculateSALE(QModelIndex colPosition);
```

from somewhere else in the program. **THIS IS PSUDO CODE OF WHAT I WANT TO DO**:

```
QModelIndex a;
a.column=3;
calculateSALE(a):
```

Comment: Yes is a QSqlTableModel called sale.

Answer (score 1):

Here i answering my own question. The solution was simple and has nothing to do with creating a "fake" QModelIndex to call the function.

```
connect(sale,SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex,QVector<int>)),this,SLOT(calculateSALE(QModelIndex)))
```

This function was doing a bunch of calculations for a specific column contained in the QModelIndex. The problem was that i wanted to iterate this function to update all the columns at once on certain occasions. The solution was to move all the code to a function that i can call from anywhere in the code lets say void updateColumn(int x). Then i had the function on the slot grab the column from the QModelIndex and call this new function.